# How to create a comment in Azure DevOps PR in case of build failure?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, pull-request, tfs-code-review

I have a custom build step that fails under certain conditions during my Pull Request build, within Azure DevOps.

I would like to extend it further by raising a PR comment, similar to this sort of thing in GitHub:
https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment

I don't have code samples to add here as I could not find useful examples to build upon. I use PowerShell for my custom build step - how do I achieve this when running a PR build of my branch?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a PR comment for the specific pull request in the PR build pipeline?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I can help with an example. There is a bunch of value in posting custom messages\status to PRs from your pipelines.

First things first, make sure your build service has permissions to contribute to pull requests in your repository.

[image: permissions]

Then you want to add a conditional PowerShell step. This one is just based on it being a PR build, but you might want to add a depends on failure for the previous step, based on your workflow.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
  displayName: Post Message to PR
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)  
  inputs:
      targetType: filePath
      filePath: PostToPR.ps1
```

So the basic workflow is:

- Build the Markdown Message
- Build the JSON Body
- Post the Message to the PR

#### PostToPR.ps1

```
#Going to create the comment in an Active state, assuming it needs to be resolved
#See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.commentthreadstatus?view=azure-devops-dotnet
$StatusCode = 1 

$Stuff = $env:Build_Repository_Name
$Things = "Other things you might want in the message"

#Build Up a Markdown Message to 
$Markdown = @"
## Markdown Message here
|Column0 |Column1|
|--------|---------|
|$Stuff|$Things|  
"@

#Build the JSON body up
$body = @"
{
    "comments": [
      {
        "parentCommentId": 0,
        "content": "$Markdown",
        "commentType": 1
      }
    ],
    "status": $StatusCode 
  }
"@

Write-Debug $Body
#Post the message to the Pull Request
#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20threads?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
try {
    $url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/git/repositories/$($env:Build_Repository_Name)/pullRequests/$($env:System_PullRequest_PullRequestId)/threads?api-version=5.1"
    Write-Host "URL: $url"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Body $Body -ContentType application/json
  if ($response -ne $Null) {
    Write-Host "*******************Bingo*********************************"
  }
}
catch {
  Write-Error $_
  Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}
```

And you end up with a nice markdown table with custom status information in your PR!

[image]

Comment: Fantastically in-depth but concise example! Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if this is because I run that on Ubuntu build host, but `Build_Repository_Name` and `System_PullRequest_PullRequestId` have to be UPPER_CASED - otherwise there is no value.

Comment: This just totally helped me out - thank you sir :)

Comment: To get the `env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` accessible you need to enable the option in your Agent job, toggle the checkbox _allow scripts to access the OAuth token_

Comment: How to update comment when there is a new code change pushed to the PR?

Answer (score 10):

Building on the great answers already provided, this is the equivalent inline YAML pipeline script:

```yaml
  - powershell: |
      $body = @"
      {
          "comments": [
            {
              "parentCommentId": 0,
              "content": "Your comment here",
              "commentType": 1
            }
          ],
          "status": 4
        }
      "@
      $url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/git/repositories/$($env:Build_Repository_Name)/pullRequests/$($env:System_PullRequest_PullRequestId)/threads?api-version=5.1"
      $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Body $Body -ContentType application/json
    displayName: Post comment on PR
```

Comment: I had to use `$env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME` and `$env:env:SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTID`

Answer (score 5):

If you mean creating PR comment in the build pipeline, then you can add a PowerShell task in your pipeline and run the script to call the REST API ([Pull Request Thread Comments - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20thread%20comments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)).

Below PowerShell script for your reference:

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}",
   [string]$projectName = "0508-t",
   [string]$repositoryId = "62c8ce54-a7bb-4e08-8ed7-40b27831bd8b",
   [string]$pullRequestId = "35",
   [string]$threadId = "229",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"  
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
write-host $WorkitemType

#Create Jason body

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
{
  "content": "Test Comment 0204",
  "parentCommentId": 1,
  "commentType": 1
}
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$baseurl/$projectName/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/pullRequests/$pullRequestId/threads/$threadId/comments?api-version=5.1"
Write-Host $uri
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Comment: Great example. And very readable code too :) #Upvote