# Azure Devops REST API - Add a review comment to a PR

Tags: azure, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-rest-api

I wanted to add a review comment for a change in a specific file and line within a pull request. I couldn't find the appropriate REST API for this task. I only came across the ['Create Thread Comment'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-thread-comments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) REST API, but it doesn't provide a way to specify the file or the specific line I'm commenting on.
Is there any way to perform this task with their REST API? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no direct Azure DevOps Rest API to add the comment on a specific PR.

But you can refer the [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63344539/automatically-adding-comments-to-all-pull-requests-in-azure-devops) here by Tyler Murry and install [**this**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tylermurry.pr-auto-comment) extension in your Azure DevOps.

> [image]

And refer the answer by Leo Liu and GaTechThomas on the same thread.

One more Rest API you can call to get the merge details of your PR is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-threads/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#commentthreadcontext) and to Get the Pull request by ID [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-request-by-id?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP):-

My Powershell code to call the Rest API:-

```
$PAT = "xxxxh2xxodglwq"
$OrgName = "xxxsai0738"
$ProjectName = "AzureDevops"
$ApiVersion = "7.0"

$services = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/$ProjectName/_apis/git/pullrequests/11?api-version=7.0" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}

$services.value
#GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=7.0
```

[image]