# Can I automatically add comments to Azure DevOps PR based on code changes

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, pull-request

Occasionally in our codebase we need to use an `//eslint-disable` to bypass a styleguide rule on a line. I would like to somehow automatically add a comment on each *new* instance of that in PRs, requiring the developer to explain why they bypassed the styleguide.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048492/how-to-create-a-comment-in-azure-devops-pr-in-case-of-build-failure) referencing how to create a comment programmatically, but what I'm not sure how to do is identify the new code and parse it for a certain piece of text, then add comments on those particular lines where the text was found.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the approaches to ingest scripts & achieve what you want, wherein *Expected outcome is:
On every pull request, a pre build validation pipeline kicks off & adds comments on the PR.*

Create a script (powershell/python/bash) with following logic:

1. **Find file names** in the given branch which contains `//eslint-disable`
2. In the files above (1.), **get the location/line number** of `//eslint-disable`
3. Foreach file.LineNumber (wrote like that just for representation): **add comment on file.LineNumber using [Pull Request Threads API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-threads/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#comment-on-a-specific-file-in-the-pull-request)**. See [line parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-threads/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#commentposition)

**Create** a pipeline containing above script & **add that pipeline as [build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation)** or if you have an existing build validation process, add these scripts as tasks in that pipeline.

Hope this helps :)