# Why am I unable to add a System.Int32 type to the PropertiesCollection

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powershell-core

I am following along using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60049855) on how to post comments to PRs in Azure Pipelines and am attempting to add some custom properties to my POST request.

Following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-threads/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#propertiescollection) I should be able to just add a key/value pair and away I go.

```
# Build the JSON body up
$body = @"
{
 "comments": [
    {
      "parentCommentId": 0,
      "content": "$content",
      "commentType": 1
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "ComposerDenyStatus": true
    }
  },
  "status": $status 
}
"@
```

The above body results in a response of:

```json
"properties": {
  "composerDenyStatus": {
    "$type": "System.String",
    "$value": "true"
  }
},
```

So I tried

```
# Build the JSON body up
$body = @"
{
 "comments": [
    {
      "parentCommentId": 0,
      "content": "$content",
      "commentType": 1
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "ComposerDenyStatus": {
      '$type': "System.Int32",
      '$value': "1"
    }
  },
  "status": $status 
}
"@
```

Which gave me `properties: null`

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're over complicating it. Try just `"ComposerDenyStatus": 1`

Comment: Comes out as a string though, but yes I am overcomplicating it :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out single quote strings don't work the same inside a PowerShell `here-string`.

You need to use backticks

```
  "properties": {
    "ComposerDenyStatus": {
      "`$type": "System.Int32",
      "`$value": "1"
    }
```